# Clean up "time" and/or "constant" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

I noticed an [old question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/131699/51760) about time constants which is tagged with [time](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant) as if the asker intended to tag the question with [time-constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-constant) (which does exist). Then I noticed [another one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/137764/51760).

I think both of these questions should be tagged [time-constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-constant).

But what about [time](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant), which have 68 and 11 questions, respectively?

[time](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) seems to be useful for some of [its questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), such as those which involve determining system time, measuring a time, or perhaps to refer to time domain as opposed to frequency domain. On the other hand, there are questions about settling and charging time for which it may not be appropriate, and there are questions which should instead be tagged with the existing and more specific [lifetime](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifetime) (e.g. [this one about battery lifetime](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/155723/51760)).

[constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant) doesn't seem to be particularly useful for any of [its questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant). It is mostly used in questions about constant voltage, constant current, constant power, etc. There is already a [constant-current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant-current) tag, and in any case [voltage-source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-source), [current-source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-source) or [constant-current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant-current), and [power-supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) seem to be better tags for these questions.

What should be done with [time](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant)? Should they be removed entirely? Should we simply clean up those questions tagged with them that can be re-tagged with more specific tags? Should we not bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [constant] tag is an easy decision: all of the questions in the tag have other tags, so nothing would be untagged after it's removed. I vote to burn it.

Comment: The tag has been removed from all questions.