# Should we blacklist the [constant] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist-request

Quite a few questions that are about constant voltage or constant current sources are often incorrectly tagged with [constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant) and either [voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage) or [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current). We already have [constant-current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant-current) (and theoretically [constant-voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant-voltage)) so I've fixed the tags on these questions. There are also a number of questions about time constants which were tagged [time](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant) instead of the correct [time-constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-constant), an issue which I also recently fixed and which [I brought up years ago](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5426/51760).

As it stands [constant](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant) is only used on two more questions, and it is used in the context of VHDL / Verilog constants. I don't see much use for the tag on these questions, either, so I think it should be removed. That would leave it on 0 questions.

Furthermore, since the tag keeps re-appearing in various contexts we (1) can't just make it a synonym of a better tag and (2) will need to keep removing it as it is created over and over again. Thus, it seems to be a [good candidate to be a blacklisted (i.e. blocked) tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/299342). Or is there some type of question which it belongs on?

Comment: Just a comment that today, I for one, never use "blacklist" and "whitelist." They are very [archaic terms](https://www.techspot.com/news/85631-github-replace-terms-whitelist-blacklist-masterslave-racially-insensitive.html) according to many.

Comment: @rdtsc They are only archaic terms for people who don't understand that photosensitive masks have nothing to do with US-specific racial problems.

Comment: @BrtH They are less clear than alternatives, and should probably be avoided for new projects. (However, “the tag blacklisẗ” is the official SE name for this, by which you can find all the documentation on [meta.se], so there's little we can do about this one.)

Comment: I've always associated the terms blacklist and whitelist with the actual colors referenced by the eye, and have never even considered that they are associated with race or the color of skin at any point in my life.

Comment: I really can't think of a question (in the context of EE.SE) where the term `constant` would have any particular meaning. Even for software, the terms `const` and perhaps `const-expr` would still be better than just this term. YMMV.

Comment: Why this tag still exists though

Comment: @VoltageSpike Can we get this tag blacklisted? I just cleaned up a couple more questions using it again.